# JavaScript aC undefined variable error

Tags: javascript

http://pastebin.com/YysAqpQ5

I have this script and It's getting an aC variable undefined when it calls the aC.checkStreamUpdates function on line 447. In reference to the aC.newestUpdate variable I believe. I've added an alert just for testing purposes. Any Ideas? It worked fine before I wrapped this into the main function.

You can see why I wrapped all my code into the main function in lines 655 to 664.

Comment: Please reduce your problem to just the relevant bits, and post that code here.

Comment: Also, consider indenting the code. I opened up the link and promptly decided it wasn't worth my time to inspect -- proper indents are worth a thousand...

Comment: if you read the second line you would find a link to a proper indentation version...

Comment: "Also, consider indenting the code. I opened up the link and promptly decided it wasn't worth my time to inspect -- proper indents are worth a thousand..." -- if you want people to look, paste the correctly indented code.

Comment: it's indentation is perfectly fine and beneficial in many ways...

Comment: Yes. Like the ways of *not being able to tell when functions or object literals end.*

Comment: for example would you indent everything inside the $(document).ready function. yes... me no... why because there is no reason to add an indent to every single thing. just indent inside the containing functions...

Comment: just by the way the first 27 lines are the only ones without indents... don't be so quick to judge.

Answer (score 1):

You've only defined `aC` as a local variable inside of `function main()`.  So if course it will not be visible in any other context.

If you're the one that added the `main()` wrapper it should be obvious why that caused things to break.  Without that wrapper `aC` would be declared in the global scope, and thus visible from any context.

If you want to keep your `main()` function *and* have the code work, remove the `var` keyword from the `var aC = ...` line.

You've also seem to have code that tries to make use of `aC` before `main()` is actually called.  Note that this will not work, because `aC` will not be defined in *any* scope until after `main()` has been called.  So lines like this one:

```
$(document.documentElement).keydown(aC.onKeyDown);
```

...are going to error out.  You need to move the call to `main()` so that it executes *before* any such code.  Or move any such code so that it is after the call to `main()`, same difference.

Comment: if i declare aC as a global variable it still fails... hmmm

Comment: Well you also have a bunch of code that references `aC` *before* you actually call `main()`.  You need to call `main()` first, prior to executing any code that makes a reference to `aC`.

Comment: i don't see how i'm referencing aC before calling main?

Comment: Doesn't the definition of `main()` end on line 457 (in http://pastebin.com/YysAqpQ5)?  Maybe it doesn't, it's hard to tell because the indentation is off.  If it does, then line 459 will fail.

Comment: everything is actually inside the main function so everything should have access to the local variables defined within. and for some reason my previous testing of making aC a global failed which really left me baffled. it worked this time i tried it. but it'd like to keep it a local variable...

Comment: also aroth main is the first thing that's executed otherwise the main function would be useless......

Comment: no line 456 ends the checkStreamUpdates function. line 457 ends the parent aC var object.....

Comment: anyway anyone with a decent set of programming skills can tell that this method of calling something within the setInterval or setTimeout functions will use the global namespace i.e. window instead of the local namespace in the following method and someone with a brain bigger than a pea should have been able to spot this out. sometimes i wonder how people get credit sometimes i mean seriously. don't you hate careless mistakes like this...

`setInterval("aC.checkStreamUpdates()",30000);
// should have been
setInterval(function(){ aC.checkStreamUpdates() },30000);`